# how to add folder path in foreach value in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a table, name is templates. In which id and image_name field is present. in image_name value is image1.png, image2.png. Now I have to send image_name with its folder path in JSON to postman.
I tried with this. But don't think it will not work.

My controller is:

```
public function TemplateList()
{
    $items = array();
    $templates = TemplateList::all();

    foreach($templates as $key=>$value)
    {
        $items['key'][] = $key;
        $items['value'][] = 'www.xyz.com/images/'.$value;
    }

    if ($templates->count()) {

        $data = collect(["status" => ["code" => "100", "message" => "Success", "data" => $items]]);
    } else {
        $data = collect(["status" => [ "code" => "101", "message" => "No Records"]]);
    }
    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

If I do not use foreach loop then in result is:

```
{
"status": {
    "code": "100",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 66,
            "tempimage": "template1.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "tempimage": "template2.png"
        },
```

But when I use foreach loop the result is:

```
{
"status": {
    "code": "100",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "key": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            18,
            19,
            20,
            21,
            22,
            23,
            24,
            25,
            26,
            27,
            28,
            29
        ],
        "value": [
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":66,\"tempimage\":\"template1.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":67,\"tempimage\":\"template2.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":68,\"tempimage\":\"template3.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":69,\"tempimage\":\"template4.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":70,\"tempimage\":\"template5.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":71,\"tempimage\":\"template6.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":72,\"tempimage\":\"template7.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":73,\"tempimage\":\"template8.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":74,\"tempimage\":\"template9.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":75,\"tempimage\":\"template10.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":76,\"tempimage\":\"template11.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":77,\"tempimage\":\"template12.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":78,\"tempimage\":\"template13.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":79,\"tempimage\":\"template14.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":80,\"tempimage\":\"template15.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":81,\"tempimage\":\"template16.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":82,\"tempimage\":\"template17.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":83,\"tempimage\":\"template18.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":84,\"tempimage\":\"template19.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":85,\"tempimage\":\"template20.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":86,\"tempimage\":\"template21.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":87,\"tempimage\":\"template22.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":88,\"tempimage\":\"template23.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":89,\"tempimage\":\"template24.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":90,\"tempimage\":\"template25.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":91,\"tempimage\":\"template26.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":92,\"tempimage\":\"template27.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":93,\"tempimage\":\"template28.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":94,\"tempimage\":\"template29.png\"}",
            "www.xyz.com/images/{\"id\":95,\"tempimage\":\"template30.png\"}"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your foreach loop you are creating two new arrays with keys `key` and `value`, you need to put the data together as so:

```
public function TemplateList()
{
    $items = array();
    $templates = TemplateList::all();

    foreach($templates as $key=>$value)
    {
        $items[] = [
            'key' => $value['id'],
            'value' => 'www.xyz.com/images/'.$value['tempimage']
        ];
    }

    if ($templates->count()) {

        $data = collect(["status" => ["code" => "100", "message" => "Success", "data" => $items]]);
    } else {
        $data = collect(["status" => [ "code" => "101", "message" => "No Records"]]);
    }
    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```